# Browser-caching iframe source

Tags: html, caching, iframe, browser-cache, prefetch

I'm trying to [prefetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) an iframe resource that I will later use. However, the browser seems to never be caching this iframe src, rendering the prefetch useless. I couldn't find any special caching rule that applies to iframes, so I'm confused about this behavior. Please see this screenshot: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/17tuIGRc9WKUNXS4_bfwzhn5RC201BGM0/view?usp=sharing` from Network inspector in Chrome 63.

Does anyone know why the iframe document is not being cached and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Chrome Dev Tools has a bug - it does not state an iframe source has been loaded from the browser cache when it indeed has. I've filed a bug for it.